# (tornado)how can I pass argument to server when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, tornado

I'm new to python tornado.I'm now building a web site
When I want to send an argument to server by pressing a button,I don't know how to catch it on tornado.
How do I know which button was pressed ?

Comment: what type of action you want to do with this event? If you want to display a message, you can do it with javascript. If you just want to make a python task on server side you can do it with an ajax GET request on a dedicated url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple ajax GET request with jquery can do the job :

```python
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    """Tornado web class. Create all the routes used by tornado_start"""

    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", Index),
            (r"/explicit_action_url/", ActionHandler)
        ]
...

class ActionHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print("button click")


class Index(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")
```

and in your index.html

```js
<button id="btn" type="button">click me</button>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/explicit_action_url/",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This solution works, but it misses the part that the OP wants to know which button was pressed, this could simply be the passing of the button ID to the Tornado handler upon clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a websocket handler class that subclasses from tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler), and in your handler class you override the on_message method.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/websocket.html

Comment: why a websocket ? this solution does not work for old browser